# Users create script from CSV file

Tags: bash, scripts

Im trying to get this script working but what I get is:

> 14: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "fi").

Hope you guys can solve my problem because it's been a while Im looking into the error...
If you need the `.csv` file let me know.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
filein="proyecto3.csv"
IFS=$'\n'
if [ ! -f "$filein" ]
then
echo "Cannot find file $filein"
else
  groups=(`cut -d: -f 6 "$filein" | sed 's/ //'`)
  fullnames=(`cut -d: -f 1 "$filein"`)
  userid=(`cut -d: -f 2 "$filein"`)
  usernames=(`cut -d: -f 1 "$filein" | tr [A-Z] [a-z] | awk '{print substr($1,1,1) $2}'`)
fi
for group in ${groups[*]}
do
grep -q "^$group" /etc/group ; let x=$?
if [ $x -eq 1 ]
then
groupadd "$group"
fi
done
  x=0
  created=0
for user in ${usernames[*]}
do
useradd -n -c ${fullnames[$x]} -g "${groups[$x]}" $user 2> /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
let created=$created+1
fi
echo "${usernames[$x]}" | passwd --stdin "$user" > /dev/null
echo "Complete. $created accounts have been created."
fi
```

Comment: the last `fi` in last line is extar I think

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply remove the very last line in your script (also it helps to do a proper indentation to see your errors). Also you forgot to end your last for loop with a done:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
filein="proyecto3.csv"
IFS=$'\n'

if [ ! -f "$filein" ]
then
    echo "Cannot find file $filein"
else
    groups=(`cut -d: -f 6 "$filein" | sed 's/ //'`)
    fullnames=(`cut -d: -f 1 "$filein"`)
    userid=(`cut -d: -f 2 "$filein"`)
    usernames=(`cut -d: -f 1 "$filein" | tr [A-Z] [a-z] | awk '{print substr($1,1,1) $2}'`)
fi

for group in ${groups[*]}
do
    grep -q "^$group" /etc/group ; let x=$?
    if [ $x -eq 1 ]
    then
        groupadd "$group"
    fi
done

x=0 #not sure why you reset x here to zero !?
created=0

for user in ${usernames[*]}
do
    useradd -n -c ${fullnames[$x]} -g "${groups[$x]}" $user 2> /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        let created=$created+1
    fi
done

echo "${usernames[$x]}" | passwd --stdin "$user" > /dev/null
echo "Complete. $created accounts have been created."
```

Up to that I can really advise you to use something like `shellcheck` on your script ( you can get it from the normal Ubuntu universe repositories).

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install shellcheck
```

It outputs a lot more you can do better on your script:

```
$ shellcheck test.sh

In test.sh line 9:
    groups=(`cut -d: -f 6 "$filein" | sed 's/ //'`)
            ^-- SC2006: Use $(..) instead of legacy `..`.


In test.sh line 10:
    fullnames=(`cut -d: -f 1 "$filein"`)
               ^-- SC2006: Use $(..) instead of legacy `..`.


In test.sh line 11:
    userid=(`cut -d: -f 2 "$filein"`)
    ^-- SC2034: userid appears unused. Verify it or export it.
            ^-- SC2006: Use $(..) instead of legacy `..`.


In test.sh line 12:
    usernames=(`cut -d: -f 1 "$filein" | tr [A-Z] [a-z] | awk '{print substr($1,1,1) $2}'`)
               ^-- SC2006: Use $(..) instead of legacy `..`.
                                            ^-- SC2060: Quote parameters to tr to prevent glob expansion.
                                                  ^-- SC2060: Quote parameters to tr to prevent glob expansion.


In test.sh line 29:
    useradd -n -c ${fullnames[$x]} -g "${groups[$x]}" $user 2> /dev/null
                  ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
                                                      ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.


In test.sh line 30:
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
         ^-- SC2181: Check exit code directly with e.g. 'if mycmd;', not indirectly with $?.
```

Alternatively, use the [online shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net/) tool...

Comment: upvoted for the recommendation of shellcheck. Nice tool!

Comment: Hello, thanka  lot for the tips, really appreciated.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark beside it.

Comment: Yes I know but I still have a problem and I was going to write it in another post.